# Python/Cython/C and callbacks, calling a Python function from C using Cython

Tags: python, c, function, callback, cython

I have the following question.
We have to pass callback functions to the C code. If the function is a Cython function in the same module, the situation is quite simple

In Cython:

```
def callme(int x):
    c_callme(x, <int (*)(int)>&callbackme) 

cdef int callbackme(int x):
    print <int> x
    return <int>x
```

In C:

```
int c_callme(int x, int (*f)(int))
{
    printf("---%d\n",x);
    printf("--%d\n",f(x));
    return x;
}
```

The question is as follows: we want to generalize this code in the most Pythonic way so that it can accept also python functions as callback arguments (of course, some additional layer is needed), and also C/Cython functions from another module. I suppose, for C/Cython functions from a separate module one has to get the address of these functions (convert to long int?) and for Python function a certain wrapper is needed

Comment: Please read the FAQ about code formatting...

Comment: If you want wrap different functions at the same time (so one global variable isn't enough), there is no way around code generated at run-time. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51054667/5769463

Answer (score 15):

In this example, [extracted from a Python wrapper](https://github.com/saullocastro/cubature/blob/master/cubature/_cubature.pyx) to the [Cubature integration C library](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/Cubature), a Python function is passed to a C function that has the prototype given by `cfunction`. You can create a function with the same prototype, called `cfunction_cb` (callback), and returning the same type, `int` in this example):

```
cdef object f
ctypedef int (*cfunction) (double a, double b, double c, void *args)

cdef int cfunction_cb(double a, double b, double c, void *args):
    global f
    result_from_function = (<object>f)(a, b, c, *<tuple>args)
    for k in range(fdim):
        fval[k] = fval_buffer[k]
    return 0
```

When calling the C function, you can cast your callback wrapper using the C prototype:

```
def main(pythonf, double a, double b, double c, args): 
    global f
    f = pythonf
    c_function( <cfunction> cfunction_cb,
                double a,
                double b,
                double c,
                <void *> args )
```

In this example it is also shown how to pass arguments to your Python function, through C.

Comment: this should be accepted as answer, it works fine. The global instance keeps the instance alive and well.

Comment: It should be `c_function(&cfunction_cb,...)` and not `c_function(<cfunction>cfunction_cb,...)` because the version with `<cfunction>` will cast any function to cfunction-functor and one will see the problems only during the run time. For version with `&`, the compiler will catch a possible type mismatch.

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest way would be to wrap C callbacks in

```
cdef class Callback(object):
    cdef int (*f)(int)        # I hope I got the syntax right...

    def __call__(int x):
        return self.f(x)
```

so you can pass objects of this type, as well as any other callable, to the function that must call the callback.

However, if you must call the callback from C, then you should may pass it an extra argument, namely the optional address of a Python object, perhaps cast to `void*.

(Please do *not* cast function pointers to `long`, or you may get undefined behavior. I'm not sure if you can safely cast a function pointer to anything, even `void*`.)

Comment: I was also thinking in that direction. But the code does not  compile at all :( . Can you elaborate more on why we do not have to cast function pointers to long?

Comment: @IvanOseledets: function pointer values are not guaranteed to fit in `long`, and vice versa. It might work on one machine, but fail on another. That this code doesn't compile is probably due to a syntax error, I don't have a Cython installation handy.