# Making a Cython wrapper around Python function

Tags: python, c, function, callback, cython

I have a C function which signature looks like this:

```
typedef double (*func_t)(double*, int)
int some_f(func_t myFunc);
```

I would like to pass a Python function (not necessarily explicitly) as an argument for some_f. Unfortunately, I can't afford to alter declaration of some_f, that's it: I shouldn't change C code.

One obvious thing I tried to do is to create a basic wrapping function like this:

```
cdef double wraping_f(double *d, int i /*?, object f */):
     /*do stuff*/
     return <double>f(d_t)
```

However, I can't come up with a way to actually "put" it inside wrapping_f's body.

There is a very bad solution to this problem: I could use a global object variable, however this forces me copy-n-paste multiple instances of essentially same wrapper function that will use different global functions (I am planning to use multiple Python functions simultaneously).

Comment: Have a look at the second half of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34900829/4657412. The difficulty is that you want to have some state attached to your function pointer (so it knows what python object to call) and C function pointers cannot store state. Therefore, I believe it's genuinely impossible in standard C. The only way I've found to do it is to use ctypes or cffi which manage to do it using some (hidden) non-standard hacks (generating code at runtime)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I keep my other answer for historical reasons - it shows, that there is no way to do what you want without jit-compilation and helped me to understand how great @DavidW's advise in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34900829/5769463) was.

For the sake of simplicity, I use a slightly simpler signature of functions and trust you to change it accordingly to your needs.

Here is a blueprint for a closure, which lets `ctypes` do the jit-compilation behind the scenes:

```
%%cython
#needs Cython > 0.28 to run because of verbatim C-code 
cdef extern from *:   #fill some_t with life
    """
    typedef int (*func_t)(int);
    static int some_f(func_t fun){
        return fun(42);
    }
    """
    ctypedef int (*func_t)(int)
    int some_f(func_t myFunc)

#works with any recent Cython version:
import ctypes
cdef class Closure:
    cdef object python_fun
    cdef object jitted_wrapper

    def inner_fun(self, int arg):
        return self.python_fun(arg)

    def __cinit__(self, python_fun):
        self.python_fun=python_fun
        ftype = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int,ctypes.c_int) #define signature
        self.jitted_wrapper=ftype(self.inner_fun)           #jit the wrapper

    cdef func_t get_fun_ptr(self):
        return (<func_t *><size_t>ctypes.addressof(self.jitted_wrapper))[0]

def use_closure(Closure closure):
    print(some_f(closure.get_fun_ptr()))
```

And now using it:

```
>>> cl1, cl2=Closure(lambda x:2*x), Closure(lambda x:3*x)
>>> use_closure(cl1)
84
>>> use_closure(cl2)
126
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is more in Do-It-Yourself style and while not unintersting you should refer to my other answer for a concise recept.

---

This answer is a hack and a little bit over the top, it only works for Linux64 and probably should not be recommended - yet I just cannot stop myself from posting it.

There are actually four versions:

- how easy the life could be, if the API would take the possibility of closures into consideration
- using a global state to produce a single closure [also considered by you]
- using multiple global states to produce multiple closures at the same time [also considered by you]
- using jit-compiled functions to produce an arbitrary number of closures at the same time

For the sake of simplicity I chose a simpler signature of `func_t` - `int (*func_t)(void)`.

I know, you cannot change the API. Yet I cannot embark on a journey full of pain, without mentioning how simple it could be... There is a quite common trick to fake closures with function pointers - just add an additional parameter to your API (normally `void *`), i.e:

```
#version 1: Life could be so easy
# needs Cython >= 0.28 because of verbatim C-code feature
%%cython 
cdef extern from *: #fill some_t with life
    """
    typedef int (*func_t)(void *);
    static int some_f(func_t fun, void *params){
        return fun(params);
    }
    """
    ctypedef int (*func_t)(void *)
    int some_f(func_t myFunc, void *params)

cdef int fun(void *obj):
    print(<object>obj)
    return len(<object>obj)

def doit(s):
    cdef void *params = <void*>s
    print(some_f(&fun, params))
```

We basically use `void *params` to pass the inner state of the closure to `fun` and so the result of `fun` can depend on this state.

The behavior is as expected:

```
>>> doit('A')
A
1
```

But alas, the API is how it is. We could use a global pointer and a wrapper to pass the information:

```
#version 2: Use global variable for information exchange
# needs Cython >= 0.28 because of verbatim C-code feature
%%cython 
cdef extern from *:
    """
    typedef int (*func_t)();
    static int some_f(func_t fun){
        return fun();
    }
    static void *obj_a=NULL;
    """
    ctypedef int (*func_t)()
    int some_f(func_t myFunc)
    void *obj_a

cdef int fun(void *obj):
    print(<object>obj)
    return len(<object>obj)

cdef int wrap_fun():
    global obj_a
    return fun(obj_a)

cdef func_t create_fun(obj):
    global obj_a
    obj_a=<void *>obj
    return &wrap_fun


def doit(s):
    cdef func_t fun = create_fun(s)
    print(some_f(fun))
```

With the expected behavior:

```
>>> doit('A')
A
1
```

`create_fun` is just convenience, which sets the global object and return the corresponding wrapper around the original function `fun`.

NB: It would be safer to make `obj_a` a Python-object, because `void *` could become dangling - but to keep the code nearer to versions 1 and 4 we use `void *` instead of `object`.

But what if there are more than one closure in use at the same time, let's say 2? Obviously with the approach above we need 2 global objects and two wrapper functions to achieve our goal:

```
#version 3: two function pointers at the same time
%%cython 
cdef extern from *:
    """
    typedef int (*func_t)();
    static int some_f(func_t fun){
        return fun();
    }
    static void *obj_a=NULL;
    static void *obj_b=NULL;
    """
    ctypedef int (*func_t)()
    int some_f(func_t myFunc)
    void *obj_a
    void *obj_b

cdef int fun(void *obj):
    print(<object>obj)
    return len(<object>obj)

cdef int wrap_fun_a():
    global obj_a
    return fun(obj_a)

cdef int wrap_fun_b():
    global obj_b
    return fun(obj_b)

cdef func_t create_fun(obj) except NULL:
    global obj_a, obj_b
    if obj_a == NULL:
        obj_a=<void *>obj
        return &wrap_fun_a
    if obj_b == NULL:
        obj_b=<void *>obj
        return &wrap_fun_b
    raise Exception("Not enough slots")

cdef void delete_fun(func_t fun):
    global obj_a, obj_b
    if fun == &wrap_fun_a:
        obj_a=NULL
    if fun == &wrap_fun_b:
        obj_b=NULL

def doit(s):
    ss = s+s
    cdef func_t fun1 = create_fun(s)
    cdef func_t fun2 = create_fun(ss)
    print(some_f(fun2))
    print(some_f(fun1))
    delete_fun(fun1)
    delete_fun(fun2)
```

After compiling, as expected:

```
>>> doit('A')
AA
2
A
1
```

But what if we have to provide an arbitrary number of function-pointers at the same time?

The problem is, that we need to create the wrapper-functions at the run time, because there is no way to know how many we will need while compiling, so the only thing I can think of is to jit-compile these wrapper-functions when they are needed.

The wrapper function looks quite simple, here in assembler:

```
wrapper_fun:
    movq address_of_params, %rdi      ; void *param is the parameter of fun
    movq address_of_fun, %rax         ; addresse of the function which should be called
    jmp  *%rax                        ;jmp instead of call because it is last operation
```

The addresses of `params` and of `fun` will be known at run time, so we just have to link - replace the placeholder in the resulting machine code.

In my implementation I'm following more or less this great article:  https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2017/adventures-in-jit-compilation-part-4-in-python/

```
#4. version: jit-compiled wrapper
%%cython   

from libc.string cimport memcpy

cdef extern from *:
    """
    typedef int (*func_t)(void);
    static int some_f(func_t fun){
        return fun();
    }
    """
    ctypedef int (*func_t)()
    int some_f(func_t myFunc)



cdef extern from "sys/mman.h":
       void *mmap(void *addr, size_t length, int prot, int flags,
                  int fd, size_t offset);    
       int munmap(void *addr, size_t length);

       int PROT_READ  #  #define PROT_READ  0x1     /* Page can be read.  */
       int PROT_WRITE #  #define PROT_WRITE 0x2     /* Page can be written.  */
       int PROT_EXEC  #  #define PROT_EXEC  0x4     /* Page can be executed.  */

       int MAP_PRIVATE    # #define MAP_PRIVATE  0x02    /* Changes are private.  */
       int MAP_ANONYMOUS  # #define MAP_ANONYMOUS  0x20    /* Don't use a file.  */


#                             |-----8-byte-placeholder ---|
blue_print =      b'\x48\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'  # movabs 8-byte-placeholder,%rdi
blue_print+=      b'\x48\xb8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'  # movabs 8-byte-placeholder,%rax
blue_print+=      b'\xff\xe0'                                       # jmpq   *%rax ; jump to address in %rax

cdef func_t link(void *obj, void *fun_ptr) except NULL:
    cdef size_t N=len(blue_print)
    cdef char *mem=<char *>mmap(NULL, N, 
                                PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC,
                                MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS,
                                -1,0)
    if <long long int>mem==-1:
        raise OSError("failed to allocated mmap")

    #copy blueprint:
    memcpy(mem, <char *>blue_print, N);

    #inject object address:
    memcpy(mem+2, &obj, 8);

    #inject function address:
    memcpy(mem+2+8+2, &fun_ptr, 8);

    return <func_t>(mem)


cdef int fun(void *obj):
    print(<object>obj)
    return len(<object>obj)


cdef func_t create_fun(obj) except NULL:
    return link(<void *>obj, <void *>&fun)

cdef void delete_fun(func_t fun):
    munmap(fun, len(blue_print))

def doit(s):
    ss, sss = s+s, s+s+s
    cdef func_t fun1 = create_fun(s)
    cdef func_t fun2 = create_fun(ss)   
    cdef func_t fun3 = create_fun(sss)  
    print(some_f(fun2))
    print(some_f(fun1))
    print(some_f(fun3))
    delete_fun(fun1)
    delete_fun(fun2)
    delete_fun(fun3)
```

And now, the expected behavior:

```
>>doit('A')
AA
2
A
1
AAA
3
```

After looking at this, maybe there is a change the API can be changed?

Comment: I think this is a useful answer, mostly for parts 1 (the "standard" way of passing "unknown data", with `void*`) and 4 (it's good to see how you'd actually go about creating a runtime function). I think there should be a warning about "refcounting" for the `void*` approach - it's not uncommon for the callback and data pointer to saved for later, and you do need to be careful to make sure the object survives until then